Solution to $x^a = W(b x)$
While solving a more complex equation, I encountered an equation involving the (principal branch of) Lambert $W$-function shown in the title ($a$ and $b$ are constants). Inputting this into WolframAlpha gives a magical solution
$$ x = \left[ \frac{a-1}{a} W\left( \frac{a}{a-1} b^{\frac{a}{a-1}} \right) \right]^{1/a} $$
with no hint on how this is derived.
I would like to know, how one would approach arriving into this solution. I have no idea how to even start.

Hm, this is extraordinary surprising. Does Wolfram alpha show a step-by-step solution or do we need a pro-version for this ? $x^a$ is just the bracket , but $W(bx)$ is a horrible expression containing a Lambert-W function within a Lambert-W function. I am clueless either.

I suppose that they make $t=bx$  then take logarithms and use the fact that $\log (W(t))=\log (t)-W(t)$

Hint: use the substitution $bx = te^t$.

If you already have a solution, the solution path is to perform the operations in reverse order.
The transformations used to solve this type of equation are always the same.
But sometimes the appearance of the solution depends on the order in which the individual operations are applied.
Let $f,g$ unary functions and let $f^{-1}$ denote the inverse relation or a suitable partial inverse of the function $f$:
$$x=f(W(g(x)))$$
$$\implies f^{-1}(x)=W(g(x))$$
$$\implies f^{-1}(x)e^{ f^{-1}(x)}=g(x)$$
I give the solution path for real $a,b,x$.
$$x^a=W(bx)$$
$$x^ae^{x^a}=bx$$
$$x^{a-1}e^{x^a}=b$$
$$x^ae^{\frac{a}{a-1}x^a}=b^{\frac{a}{a-1}}$$
$$\frac{a}{a-1}x^ae^{\frac{a}{a-1}x^a}=\frac{a}{a-1}b^\frac{a}{a-1}$$
$$\frac{a}{a-1}x^a=W\left(\frac{a}{a-1}b^\frac{a}{a-1}\right)$$
$$x=\left(\frac{a-1}{a}W\left(\frac{a}{a-1}b^\frac{a}{a-1}\right)\right)^\frac{1}{a}$$
